# Can I open any file with any extension using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, computer-science, decoding

I am a new coder and I don't know very much about python. While surfing in Internet I found that you can open files through python. So my question is that can I open any file extension/custom file extension through python? Can I also open it as a .txt? Please if you answer, provide the code also! If possible.

Comment: Don't think of files as having types. File types specify how the file's contents should be interpreted, but doesn't actually have any bearing on the content itself. You can open an image file as a text file just fine. Of course, you'll just see a bunch of garbage characters. Data is data, and you can rename a .png to a .txt without any issues.

Comment: Yes, extensions do not mean anything, there are mostly here for humans. This doesn't mean that python can interpret any file, but it can for sure read the raw content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So my question is that can I open any file extension/custom file extension through python? Can I also open it as a .txt?

yes and yes!

You can open any text file in python by :

```py
with open("filename.txt") as x:
    ...
```

Suppose you want to read the contents of a text file then you could do :

```py
with open("filename.txt", "r") as f:
    print(f.read())
```

This program will print the contents of `filename.txt`, notice the `"r"` over there? It is to specify the mode in which you are working with the file (in simple terms, like for read / write)

Also you don't have to mention any mode when you are reading because `"r"`is the default one but you can be explicit about it

There are a few available 'modes' in which you can open an file :

Read Only (‘r’): Open text file for reading. The handle is positioned at the beginning of the file. If the file does not exist, raises I/O error. This is also the default mode in which the file is opened, as mentioned earlier.

Read and Write (‘r+’): Open the file for reading and writing. The handle is positioned at the beginning of the file. Raises I/O error if the file does not exist

Write Only (‘w’): Open the file for writing. For existing file, the data is truncated and over-written. The handle is positioned at the beginning of the file. Creates the file if the file does not exist.

Write and Read (‘w+’): Open the file for reading and writing. For existing file, data is truncated and over-written. The handle is positioned at the beginning of the file.

Append Only (‘a’): Open the file for writing. The file is created if it does not exist. The handle is positioned at the end of the file. The data being written will be inserted at the end, after the existing data.

Append and Read (‘a+’): Open the file for reading and writing. The file is created if it does not exist. The handle is positioned at the end of the file. The data being written will be inserted at the end, after the existing data.

You could also open an file by :

```
name = open(...)
```

but this generally isn't deemed the best practice because you have to manually close the file later.

> So my question is that can I open any file extension/custom file extension through python?

yes. For example you can open an image and read the bytes from it in a similar way mentioned above.

Comment: But can I open a file of my own extension (eg .Svc , .abc ) which has data in the form of text?

Comment: @NewbieCoder exact same steps but refrain from having a file named `.abc` it is used for music notation, perhaps name it `.abcd`. You can open the file with `with open("name.abcd")` and then read it like the post says.